# Java Web Services request-response issue

Tags: java, web-services, soap, keystore

I'm implementing WS-based Agent which will manage soap requests to/responses from [PCRF](http://www.huawei.com/en/products/core-network/singlesdb/upcc/index.htm). The connection is through https port and it is using Java Key Store (a key-store tool) to generate [a key-store file from a trusted certificate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/toolsign/rstep2.html). The connection seems to be OK (I'm not sure if the authentication is successful or not), but returned info (the response) is a short unreadable string.

The same procedure through [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) app is working just fine.

The only difference between both procedures is that by the 1st I'm using a key-store and by the 2nd I'm using the trusted certificate.

How can I possibly solve that? I do not understand where something goes wrong.

If it would help I can share Java source used for SOAP messages sender and the responses received from PSRF, into SoapUI and into implemented WS.

```
package SOAPSender;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class DebugMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //PCRFProvisioningAgent temp = new PCRFProvisioningAgent(); 

            loadKeyAndTrustStore();

            StringBuffer outputStream = new StringBuffer();
            BufferedWriter wr = null;
            BufferedReader rd = null;
            Socket sock = null;
            String outputBuffer = null;

            try {

                // Create socket
                sock = new Socket("10.96.227.219", 8080);

                // Create header
                wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                        sock.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));

                String xmlData = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:rm=\"rm:soap\">"+
                           "<soapenv:Header/>"+
                           "<soapenv:Body>"+
                              "<rm:getSubscriber>"+
                                 "<inPara>"+
                                    "<subscriber>"+
                                       "<attribute>"+
                                          "<key>USRIDENTIFIER</key>"+
                                          "<value>284090000000004</value>"+
                                       "</attribute>"+
                                    "</subscriber>"+
                                 "</inPara>"+
                              "</rm:getSubscriber>"+
                           "</soapenv:Body>"+
                        "</soapenv:Envelope>";              

                wr.write("POST https://10.96.227.219:8080/axis/services/ScfPccSoapServiceEndpointPort HTTP/1.1\r\n");
                wr.write("User-Agent: https://10.96.227.219:8080/axis/services/ScfPccSoapServiceEndpointPort\r\n");
                wr.write("Content-Length: " + xmlData.length() + "\r\n");
                wr.write("Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8\r\n");
//              wr.write("SOAPAction: \"rm:soap/ScfPccSoapServiceEndpoint/getSubscriberRequest\"\r\n");
                wr.write("SOAPAction: \"\"\r\n");
                wr.write("\r\n");

                // Send data
                wr.write(xmlData);
                wr.flush();

                // Read response
                // exception handler - when connection is reset instead of close
                // after sending a packet from source
                char cbuf[] = new char[4096];
                int i = 0;
                // buffer is sized to max 4096 packet size

                try {
                    rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                            sock.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
                    while ((i = rd.read(cbuf)) != -1) {
                        outputStream.append(cbuf, 0, i);
                        int contStartIndex = outputStream.toString().indexOf(
                                "Content-Length: ")
                                + "Content-Length: ".length();
                        int contEndIndex = outputStream.toString().indexOf("\n",
                                contStartIndex) - 1;
                        if (outputStream.toString().indexOf("Content-Length: ") != -1) {
                            int contLength = Integer.valueOf(
                                    outputStream.toString().substring(
                                            contStartIndex, contEndIndex))
                                    .intValue();
                            int headerLength = outputStream
                                    .toString()
                                    .substring(
                                            0,
                                            outputStream.toString().indexOf(
                                                    "\n\r\n")).length() + 3;
                            // if the message body is complete but there is not an
                            // ending character
                            // while will break
                            // warning - with national characters! content length is
                            // count of bytes not chars
                            if (i - headerLength >= contLength)
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("--------\n" + String.valueOf(cbuf)
                        + "\n--------------");
                outputBuffer = outputStream.toString();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (wr != null)
                        wr.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    if (rd != null)
                        rd.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    if (sock != null)
                        sock.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    }

    private static void loadKeyAndTrustStore() {
        try {
            // System.out.println(Constants.ROOT_PATH + Constants.STORE_FILE);
            // AdminLogger.error("Certificate file: " + Constants.ROOT_PATH
            // + Constants.STORE_FILE);

            // System load ssl the file of certificate
            // Load Key store

            System.out.println(System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType"));
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "****");
            System.out.println(System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType"));

            System.out.println(System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore"));
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore",
                    "****");
            System.out.println(System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore"));

            System.out.println(System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword"));
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "****");
            System.out.println(System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword"));


            // TrustStore

            System.out.println(System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore"));
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore",
                    "****");
            System.out.println(System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore"));

            System.out.println(System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword"));
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "****");
            System.out.println(System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword"));

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // AdminLogger.error(ex, "StartupServlet.loadKeyAndTrustStore");
        }
    }

}
```

This is the response:

[image]

...and here is the response from SoapUI app:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <getSubscriberResponse xmlns="rm:soap">
         <result xmlns="">
            <resultCode>12302</resultCode>
            <paras>
               <key>errorDescription</key>
               <value>The subscriber does not exist.</value>
            </paras>
         </result>
      </getSubscriberResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sockets is not the ideal way to invoke web services from Java. Please use a Java API like JAX-WS. Obtain the WSDL from the PSRF web service and generate the client stubs using ws-import command.

On security, you will need to use JAX-WS security API to invoke a Web service secured with WS-Security.

See this thread - [jax-ws-consuming-web-service-with-ws-security-and-ws-addressing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699254/jax-ws-consuming-web-service-with-ws-security-and-ws-addressing)

Thanks,
Sreehari.

Comment: I didn't mention that the system with sends these SOAP messages to PCRF is configured with java version 1.4.2!

Answer (score 0):

As noted by @sreehari, Sockets is an less than ideal for invoking web services - you will basically have to implement all the relevant details of the application protocol (e.g. HTTP/S) yourself. In itself that is a tremendous undertaking.

If you want to stay "low-level", and build the requests yourself, then I suggests you "upgrade" to using HttpsUrlConnection.